# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am getting the above error while running python code.
Can you please help me to solve this?

I am trying to run an SQL query and load the output file into an S3 bucket. But it is showing this error.

Running the SQL query is based on a sequence number. Jobs will triggered consecutively which run the queries, generate the files and load them into my S3 bucket.

Code:

```
def load_data():
    try:

        conn = redshift_conn()

        df_file = pd.read_csv("/medaff/Scripts/python/output_query.txt", 'r', delimiter = '|')
        print(df_file['tablename'][0])

        unique_seq_num = df_file['seq_no'].unique().tolist()
        unique_seq_num.sort()
        for exec_seq in unique_seq_num:
            temp_df = df_file[df_file['seq_no'] == exec_seq].copy()
            unique_table_name = temp_df['tablename'].unique().tolist()
            unique_sql_query = temp_df['sql'].unique().tolist()
            print(unique_table_name)
            #table_name = df_file['tablename'].unique()
            #sql = df_file['sql'].unique()

            for i in range(0,len(unique_table_name)):
                print(unique_table_name[i])
                #print(unique_sql_query[i])

                with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    cur.execute(unique_sql_query[i])
                    res = cur.fetchall()

                    #print(res)
                    with open('/medaff/Scripts/python/' + unique_table_name[i] + '.txt' , 'w') as file:
                        d = csv.writer(file, delimiter='|')
                        d.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                        d.writerows(res)

                    print(unique_table_name[i])
                    print(bucket)
                    print(access_key)
                    print(secret)
                    print(" aws s3 cp /medaff/Scripts/python/{}.txt s3://{}/{}/ --sse".format(unique_table_name[i], bucket, unique_table_name[i]))
                    os.system(" aws s3 cp /medaff/Scripts/python/{0}.txt s3://{1}/{2}/ --sse".format(unique_table_name[i], bucket, unique_table_name[i]))


                    cur.execute(" truncate table medaff.{} ".format(unique_table_name[i]))
                    print(" truncate table medaff.{} ".format(unique_table_name[i]))
                    cur.execute(" COPY medaff.{0} FROM 's3://{1}/{2}/{3}.txt' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={4};aws_secret_access_key={5}'emptyasnull blanksasnull  DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 DATEFORMAT 'auto'ENCODING AS UTF8 acceptinvchars COMPUPDATE OFF  CSV; ".format(unique_table_name[i], bucket, unique_table_name[i], unique_table_name[i], access_key, secret))
                    print(" COPY medaff.{0} FROM 's3://{1}/{2}/{3}.txt' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={4};aws_secret_access_key={5}'emptyasnull blanksasnull  DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 DATEFORMAT 'auto'ENCODING AS UTF8 acceptinvchars COMPUPDATE OFF  CSV; ".format(unique_table_name[i], bucket, unique_table_name[i], unique_table_name[i], access_key, secret))

                    '''load_query = ("insert into {} values {}".format(unique_table_name[i], res))
                    cur.execute(load_query)
                    final_res = cur.fetchall()
                    count = final_res.count()
                    print(count)'''

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iMedical_Consump_Load_Procs.py", line 79, in load_data
  print(unique_table_name[i])  
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Column
```

Comment: You redefine `i` here: `d.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])` - use a different variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because the variable `i` is getting re-initialized in the list comprehension part. Try using a different variable in list comprehension and this will solve your problem